# Proper changes were not affecting on tableview section header background

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have table view with 12 sections and each section has section header I set header background colour with alpha components(for transparency) I got transparency for 11 sections but I did not get on 12th section and when I drag `tableView` down then 11th  also got same colour like 12th and like this if I drag up also same problem for 1,2.

I've tried to do same code in cell for at `indexPath` because this method called when I drag `tableView` but I did not get

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {

    //recast your view as a UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    print("will display header view")
    let header: UITableViewHeaderFooterView = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.colorWithHexString(hexStr: "#408000").withAlphaComponent(0.2)

}
```

Comment: Do you mean that `willDisplayHeaderView` method does not get called? OR it does get called but the implementation is not working?

Comment: willDisplayHeaderView is also called but not getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implemented this functionality in this way:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.tblViewShoppingCart.frame.size.width, height: 40))
        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        let lblOrderDetails = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 15, y: 10, width: self.tblViewShoppingCart.frame.size.width, height: 30))
        lblOrderDetails.text = "ORDER DETAILS"
        lblOrderDetails.font = GLOBAL_CONSTANT.FONT_SEMIBOLD(size: 14)
        lblOrderDetails.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
         headerView.addSubview(lblOrderDetails)
        let lblSeparator = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: lblOrderDetails.frame.maxY , width: self.tblViewShoppingCart.frame.size.width, height: 1))
        lblSeparator.backgroundColor = tableView.separatorColor
        headerView.addSubview(lblSeparator)
        return headerView
    } 
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

      return 40

}
```

You can write the `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` design in the `viewForHeaderInSection` delegate method.
Hope it helps you. thank you

Comment: Please click the up arrow on my answer. Thank you